# How to tackle pipeline slow down due to `mypy --install-types`

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, mypy, lint

## Problem summary

When running `mypy` on my code, I keep getting many `Library stubs not installed` errors.

 Few examples below:

```
/opt/conda/envs/my_ci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/core/generated/agent_manager_pb2.py:5: error: Library stubs not installed for "google.protobuf.internal.enum_type_wrapper" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)
/opt/conda/envs/my_ci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/summary.py:8: error: Library stubs not installed for "six.moves" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)
/opt/conda/envs/my_ci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/rllib/algorithms/algorithm.py:28: error: Library stubs not installed for "pkg_resources" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)
```

Currently I have to use the command
`mypy --install-types --non-interactive my_folder --config-file=mypy.ini`.

And although it solves the issue, the problem now is that it takes at least 2 min for installing missing types. This is very long for our CI/CD pipeline.

## Question

What are alternative ways of addressing missing library stubs? 
 E.g., such that I could maybe 'split' mypy `install types` (or other solution that is more time-consuming and potentially can be put as part of docker image), from pure `run mypy` command (that takes less time and runs as part of gitlab ci/cd pipeline).

I tried running `mypy --install-types` command first, and then `run mypy` without success. Could it be that I am doing something wrong?

I will appreciate any help and ideas!

Comment: You can (and probably should) do it outside of your pipeline, record which packages get installed and declare them as dependencies like `additional_dependencies` in pre-commit config file or separate `requirements.dev.txt` (or even `requirements.types.txt`) file that contains all necessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches for GitLab.

1. Cache `pip`. Read [Cache Python dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-python-dependencies).
   The most important is to specify `pip` cache path:

   ```yaml
   variables:
     PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

   cache:
     paths:
       - .cache/pip
   ```
2. Build a Docker image with all dependencies included. You can use your Docker image in GitLab CI/CD.
   Building Docker images is a large topic and a bit out of scope of the current question. You can start with [Use Docker to build Docker images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) documentation.